# WCF service works only with C# client on Win7 64 bit - IE can't even see it!

Tags: wcf

I have a weird situation with WCF web service running on Win7 64 bit.

First the configuration:

.NET 3.5, WCF, web service compiled for x86, running as a console app (or Windows service, doesn't make any difference in this case).

I am using basicHttpBinding. I also have aspNetCompatibilityEnabled set to "true".

I have test clients written in C#, Java, PHP, and Ruby.

Now the issue:

Everything works just fine on XP Pro, Win7 32bit, Win server 2003, Win server 2008 R2 64 bit.

When I run on Win7 64 bit, everything installs fine and the web service starts up just fine. I can run the C# client against this service and it works. When I run Java, it errors out with "Can't connect".

Also, when I type in "http://localhost:55555/RmJobService.svc" in IE 8, it comes back with a blank page right away, suggesting a connection issue. Interestingly, when the web service isn't running, IE 8 takes a lot longer to come back with an error.

Since it works on Win server 2008 R2 64 bit, this doesn't seem to be a 32/64 bit issue.

It is strange that a C# sample can consume the service...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks!
daver

Comment: Are you sure C# client can connect? Is it definitely connecting to the server??

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in IIS 7 app pool settings to "Enable 32-bit applications."  This may help since you are compiling in x86 mode.

Comment: I am not running in IIS, but as Windows service or console. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the [metadata exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx) endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I have this in the config file:

<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexEndpoint"
          bindingNamespace="http://www.rimage.com/RmJobService" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

Using IE to test basic communications works on other platforms as well.